# Remove a layer of object using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, arraylist

I am currently using reactJS and trying to reindexing each object in hooks with the `hooks.event` inside each hooks:

```
const supervisor = {
      "hooks": [
          {
              "is_activate": true,
              "event": "ad_status_updated",
          },
          {
              "is_activate": true,
              "event": "ad_recommand_action",
          }
      ]
}
```

I want to isolate hooks and set `hooks.event` as the key for each object inside hooks.
eg:

```
 hooks = [
          "ad_status_updated": {
              "is_activate": true,
              "event": "ad_status_updated",
          },
         "ad_recommand_action": {
              "is_activate": true,
              "event": "ad_recommand_action",
          }
      ]
```

I tried the `array.map` method, and

```
supervisor.hooks.map(item => { 
  return{[item.event]: item}
})
```

and I got

```
[
          {"ad_status_updated": {
              "is_activate": true,
              "event": "ad_status_updated",
          }},
          {"ad_recommand_action": {
              "is_activate": true,
              "event": "ad_recommand_action",
          }}

]
```

My question is how do you remove the outer layer for each key?

Answer (score 2):

You know, Javascript arrays can't have a string key.
Only the object can have a string key. So you've got an syntax error here.

```js
hooks = [
          "ad_status_updated": {
              "is_activate": true,
              "event": "ad_status_updated",
          },
         "ad_recommand_action": {
              "is_activate": true,
              "event": "ad_recommand_action",
          }
      ]
```